# Convergence of approximate solutions to obstacle problem for the heat equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, reference-request, boundary-condition-at-infinity

Consider the problem 
$$(P) \qquad \begin{cases}
\min\{\partial_t u - \Delta u, u -\varphi \} = 0 & \text{ in } (0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^N \\
u(0,\cdot) = \varphi(0,\cdot) & \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^N,
\end{cases}$$

which is of interest in mathematical finance.

We can take the space dimension $$N =1,2, 3$$

and, for example, as initial datum,

```
phi[t,x] = E^(t)*(1+E^(x))
```

---

It is known that it admits one and only one *strong  solution* (that is, a continuous Sobolev function that solves the problem almost everywhere and takes the initial datum pointwise) in the class of functions $|u(t,x)| \le Ce^{\lambda |x|^2}$ ($C,\lambda>0$).

The key point is that **such solution can be obtained as the limit (as $\epsilon \to 0$) of the solutions to** 
$$(P)_\varepsilon \qquad \begin{cases}
\partial_t u - \Delta u = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}(u-\phi)^+ & \text{ in } (0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^N \\
u(0,\cdot) = \varphi(0,\cdot) & \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^N,
\end{cases}$$

where $(u-\phi)^+ = \max\{u-\phi, 0\}$ is the positive part function.

> How can I write a Mathematica code that plots and animates such solution to problem $(P)$ (approximated by solutions of $(P)_\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon$ small enough)?

If we need to (do we?), we can solve the problem on $[0,T]×[−L,L]^N$ and impose the boundary condition $u(t,\pm L)=\varphi(\pm L)$.

Comment: Maybe use `NDSolve` on the PDE, and `WhenEvent` to catch the points at which `u==phi`?

Comment: I guess I am at a loss. `DSolve` is fine with your example but `NDSolve` claims it is underdetermined.Sa,e with trying the different initial condition.

Comment: I do not expect `DSolve` to find an analytic result for all such inputs. I meant that it handled your example above, with `ic` as initial condition, whereas `NDSolve` claims it is underdetermined and returns unevaluated. I realize `DSolve` does not handle the variant with the desired initial condition in place of `ic`.

Comment: Also that question you link to is not, in my opinion, viable for this forum. There is no code to reproduce the issue, and moreover it appears not to go beyond what is already in this question.

Comment: I do not understand the expression immediately following "Consider the problem" at the beginning of the question.  Judging from the comments by others, I do not think that they understand it either.  Please explain what you are trying to compute.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I guess OP is trying to show his effort on solving the problem i.e. he managed to solve a simpler problem with _Mathematica_. If so… well, hiro, I think you'd better remove this part from your question. The solution for the simpler problem i.e.  initial value problem (to emphasize, initial value problem in infinite domain) for the heat equation is not that related to the problem you're trying to solve in my opinion, mentioning this in the question doesn't help much and even makes it confusing, I think.

Comment: I think you can add a bit more background information to your question. _Obstacle problem for the heat equation_ (together with those _Sobolev function_, etc.) are all unconversant terms (at least for me). Explaining them in more detail or adding some reference may attract more attention.

Comment: Assuming you can code the $(\cdot)^+$ operator, whatever that is, the problem $(P)_\epsilon$ seems straightforward to code for `NDSolve`, unless you really want a solution for ${\bf R}^n$, for an indeterminate $n$.

Comment: So for $n=1$, do you want a solution for $-\infty < x < \infty$?  And would a numeric approximation using `NDSolve` be acceptable (implicit in my previous comment0? If so, you don't need to find the limit, only approximate it. -- That said, I think it might be hard to get the strong solution with `NDSolve` without having some BC for $x = c$, for some $c$.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I need exactly that: an approximation for $\varepsilon$ small enough. How can I write a code to obtain that? We can solve the problem on $ [0,T] \times [-L,L]^N$ and impose $u(t, \pm L) = \varphi(\pm L)$, but why do we need that?

Comment: I could not find a clear answer to the above. Was it answered somewhere else?